# Syntax for mapping c# class types to Linq2Sql stored procedure input parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Given a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdatePerson
AS
@Name nvarchar(50),
@Age int
BEGIN
--...
END
```

When I add this to a LINQ2SQL designer it generates a c# method something like:

```
someResultType UpdatePerson(string Name, int Age);
```

How can I override this to get a working method that takes a Person object as a single parameter?

```
someResultType UpdatePerson(Person aCoolPerson);
```

Its relatively straightforward to achieve this for return types but I can seem to figure it out for input parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a partial class for your data context and provide a method which calls the generated version.

```
public partial class DataContext
{
     public someResult UpdatePerson(Person p)
     {
         return this.UpdatePerson(p.Name, p.Age);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks parker130 that is definitely the second prize solution - but what I'm really after is something that will do that class property to method parameter mapping for me, like it does with return types. But if it turns out that what I want does not exist - then I'll do exactly as you suggest.